# "Одно/одним из этих пяти вещей является движение" - как правильно?

Tags: грамотная-речь

> *Одно* из этих пяти вещей является движение.

или

> *Одним* из этих пяти вещей является движение.

Как правильно?

Answer (score 3):

Одной из этих пяти вещей является движение. (*Вещь* - существительное женского рода)